# Removing Text From Left side of alphanumeric string, different lengths of text

Tags: excel

```
=IF(LEFT(A2,3)="ABC","DEF"),RIGHT(A2,LEN(A2)-3),IF(LEFT(A2,2)="GH"),RIGHT(A2,LEN(A2)-2)
```

As this does not work, below is what I am attempting to accomplish and an example of it.

Essentially I am trying to remove the first few letters off of a SKU #. However the amount of letters before the SKU can vary and there is letters at the end of the SKU which I **do not** want removed.

```
Example:

AB12345
CDE54321XY
Z123

With a result of:
12345
54321XY
123
```

My knowledge and use of VBA is almost non-existent so I have not tried to do anything with that as I believe the line I have above could work with minor tweaking though I may be wrong.

Comment: Honestly if you think you will have a long term need to do things like this, then investing some time into learning VBA could be well worth it.  Your question is very easy to handle using regular expressions, which VBA supports.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I did not even think of Regex. No doubt that will be a better way to go!

Comment: Use the pattern `^[A-Za-z]+(.*)$`, and then replace with the first capture group `$1` or maybe `\\1`.

Answer (score 0):

It's not as good as a regular expression, and since there are only 10 digits, it turns out not too long. The below is an array formula (entered with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>):

```
=MID(A1,MIN(IFERROR(SEARCH({0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9},A1),9^99)),LEN(A1))
```

[image]

The formula will give an error (`#VALUE!`) if there are no numbers. It basically looks for the position of a digit in the string and finds the smallest one. For the first example, `SEARCH` gets the positions: `#VALUE!`, 3 (1 is at position 3), 4 (2 is at position 4), 5, 6, 7, `#VALUE!`, `#VALUE!`, `#VALUE!`, `#VALUE!`. The smallest being 3 (I'm using `IFERROR` and a big number --9^99-- so it ignores the `#VALUE!`), the `MID` will take all characters as from the 3rd character inclusive.